# Python, change function behavior depending on caller, is it possible?

Tags: python, design-patterns

In this Python code snippet:

```python
def get_something():
    return something

def do_staff():
    value = get_something()
    doit(value)

def test():
    # ?????
    doStaff()
```

What is the best way to change the value returned by `get_something` depending on if was called through `test or not`? The only restriction is that I don't want to modify `do_staff`

Comment: You can add a keyword argument to `get_something` which you can check for -- Making sure to pass the keyword argument when you're *not* calling it from `do_staff`

Comment: I suppose you could also inspect stack frames inside `do_staff`, but ... that gets messy pretty quick.  it's not something you should be doing for a problem like this :)

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @NPE get_something should return a different value depending of is called in a normal environment or in a testing environment

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"?  `get_something` is never called directly, it seems it's called by `do_staff` both ways (assuming `doStaff` and `do_staff` are the same).

Comment: Is this for unit testing? or just something that came up during implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answering the Question You Asked

You either want an optional argument to change the behavior of the function. This means you **also** need an optional argument in `do_staff`, since the real question here is how to tell `get_something` where `do_staff` was called from (`test` or elsewhere):

```
def get_something(test=False):
    if test:
        return something + test_var
    return something

def do_staff(test=False):
    value = get_something(test=test)
    return doit(value)

def test():
    return do_staff(test=True)
```

If you really, really are averse to modifying `do_staff` for some reason, you'll have to look through the stack to see if the test method is up there, as someone mentioned in the comments--but that gets ugly really quickly. Otherwise, the only way to tell how a function was called is to pass an indicator through.

### Actually Solving Your Problem

From context, though, **I think what you really want** is to know how to test this thing without having to modify too much code between test/production environments. In that case, I'd suggest a totally different approach: rather than trying to see if you were called from a certain place, just define/import a `is_debug_on` variable and use that.

```
is_debug_on = False

def get_something():
    if is_debug_on:
        pass # Do testing stuff, print statements, etc.
    return something # Do normal stuff.

def do_staff():
    value = get_something()

def test():
    is_debug_on = True
    do_staff()
    is_debug_on = False
```

Obviously this is cleaner if you can put it all inside a class, or use the `logging` package, or so forth, but this is the basic idea. You can test all your code this way and not have to remove anything when you move to production, because debug mode will be turned off. **Bonus**: when things go wrong in production, you'll be able to turn debug back on and (hopefully) get some useful information right away!

Comment: But OP doesn't want to modify `do_staff`

Comment: @askewchan Well then his only direct option is looking through the stack trace. A function can't see how it was called without either inspecting the stack or getting passed some information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Optional argument?

```
def get_something(from_test=False):
    if from_test:
        return something_test
    else:
        return something

def test():
    get_something(True)
```

Comment: But the problem is that I don't call `get_something` from `test`, and `do_staff` needs the value returned by `get_something`